# R data.table select if any row contain string

Tags: r, data.table

```
data=data.frame(    SutdentID   =c( 1,2,3,4,5,6,7   ),
    cat =c( NA,'a.b','p','o','a.b','cb',NA    ),
    fox =c( 'c.e','qq',NA,'i','k','c.b',NA  ),
    dog =c( 'zz','u','e.W','h','g','f',NA   ),
    WANT    =c( 1,1,1,0,1,0,NA  ))
```

I have 'data' and wish to create 'WANT' column which contains '1' if any string in 'cat' or 'fox' or 'dog' contains 'a.b' OR 'c.e' or "e.W'; if not 'WANT' equals to zero and if all 'cat' and 'fox' and 'dog' are NA than WANT equals to 'NA'

A data.table solution is desired!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In *base* you can use `grepl` in `apply` to test if `a.b|c.e|e.W` is in the columns `c("cat", "fox", "dog")`:

```
apply(data[,c("cat", "fox", "dog")], 1, function(x) if(all(is.na(x))) NA else
 +any(grepl("a\\.b|c\\.e|e\\.W", x)))
#[1]  1  1  1  0  1  0 NA
```

or in case you mean with *contains* is equal to, you can use `match`:

```
apply(data[,c("cat", "fox", "dog")], 1, function(x) if(all(is.na(x))) NA else
 +any(!is.na(match(x, c("a.b","c.e","e.W")))))
#[1]  1  1  1  0  1  0 NA
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this nested `ifelse` statement, `apply`the function `paste0` to all rows and `grepl` to match the various patterns:

```
data$WANT2 <- ifelse(grepl("a\\.b|c\\.e|e\\.W", apply(data, 1, paste0, collapse = " ")), 1, 
                     ifelse(grepl("NA", apply(data, 1, paste0, collapse = " ")), NA, 0))

data
  SutdentID  cat  fox  dog WANT WANT2
1         1 <NA>  c.e   zz    1     1
2         2  a.b   qq    u    1     1
3         3    p <NA>  e.W    1     1
4         4    o    i    h    0     0
5         5  a.b    k    g    1     1
6         6   cb  c.b    f    0     0
7         7 <NA> <NA> <NA>   NA    NA
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `Reduce` with `lapply`

```
out <- +( Reduce(`|`, lapply(data[, c('cat', 'fox', 'dog')],
        `%in%`, c("a.b","c.e","e.W"))))
out[rowSums(is.na(data[, c('cat', 'fox', 'dog')])) == 3] <- NA
out
#[1]  1  1  1  0  1  0 NA
```